# ADF LOOKUP not updating the required table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a lookup activity in ADF pipeline. This activity truncating then inserting a value in a single record table.

In some random occasions the activity will succeed but the table still hold the old value even though the output shows me impacted rows = 1

SQL I use in the Lookup

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE [CRM_Mapping].[IncrementalLoadLock] 
INSERT INTO [CRM_Mapping].[IncrementalLoadLock] 
SELECT 0

SELECT @@RowCount AS ImpactedRow
```

the output of this activity when it fails

```json
{
    "firstRow": {
        "ImpactedRow": 1
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "ManagedIntegrationRuntime (Australia East)",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "ManagedVNetIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
    }
}
```

The only difference I noticed when this activity doesn't update the table (event though it succeeded) is the IntegragionRuntimeQueue changes from 0 to 1.

Comment: I think you should try to use a script activity instead of the lookup activity, which is not intended to update data.

Comment: Thanks Chen.
I have read on Microsoft about this activity, so I will give it a go and I am almost sure it should work and fix that random behaviour of Lookup activity.

Answer (score 1):

As Chen Hirsh suggested try to use a script activity instead of the lookup activity.

Any of the data sources enabled by data factory and Synapse pipelines can be used by lookup activity to obtain a dataset. A configuration file or database table's information is read and returned by a lookup action. Additionally, it provides the outcome of a query or saved process. A singleton number or a collection of characteristics can be the output. it is mainly focused on returning the output.

You can carry out routine tasks with Data Manipulation Language (DML) and Data Definition Language using the script action. (DDL). Users can enter, change, remove, and obtain data from the database using DML statements like enter, UPDATE, remove, and SELECT. A database manager can build, change, and delete database objects like tables, indexes, and users using DDL statements like build, ALTER, and DROP.

**Its returning you similar output:**
[image]